# How to wait for 3rd party JavaScript function to return

Tags: javascript, jquery, opentext

Given the following snippet of code

```js
var empowerInstance = null;

function onClick_btnSendMessage() {
    var childIFrame = window.document.getElementById("editorFrame");
    if (!empowerInstance) {
        empowerInstance = EditorAPI.getInstance(childIFrame.contentWindow, window.location.origin);
    }
    empowerInstance.document.hasChanged(hasChangedCallback);
}

function hasChangedCallback(returnValue) {
    console.log("empowerInstance.document.hasChanged = " + returnValue.isDirty);
    if (returnValue.success === true && returnValue.isDirty === true) {
        empowerInstance.document.save(saveCallback);
    }
}

function saveCallback(returnValue) {
    console.log("empowerInstance.document.save = " + returnValue.success);
    if (returnValue.success === false) {
        console.log(returnValue.message);
    }
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
    if (typeof location.origin === "undefined")
        window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    document.getElementById("btnSendMessage").addEventListener("click", onClick_btnSendMessage);
});
```

Instead of wiring the button up , I'd like to fire the code from the activation of a Bootstrap tab event.

```js
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {

    onClick_btnSendMessage(); // Naive way, as this does not wait

    var target = $(e.target).attr("data-EditorUrl"); // activated tab
    var childIFrame = $("#editorFrame");
    childIFrame.attr("src", target);

});
```

So my question is "How do I wait on this function to complete before changing the source of childIFrame?".

```js
empowerInstance.document.hasChanged(hasChangedCallback);
```

I conceptually understand the use of Promises and Callbacks, but writing one that functions correctly is a different story.

**UPDATED**

This version is refactored to eliminate the button handler, thus improving readability.

The usage is also important. When the page loads for the first time it is positioned on a tab. This tab is associated to a document that is hosted in an iFrame. If the user edits this document then tries to change tabs, I'd like to invoke the check for being dirty/save, then once saved, move to the next tab/document. There is also the case that switching between tabs/documents won't cause a save because the document is not dirty.

```js
var empowerInstance = null;

function hasChangedCallback(returnValue) {
    console.log("empowerInstance.document.hasChanged = " + returnValue.isDirty);
    if (returnValue.success === true && returnValue.isDirty === true) {
        empowerInstance.document.save(saveCallback);
    }
}

function saveCallback(returnValue) {
    console.log("empowerInstance.document.save = " + returnValue.success);
    if (returnValue.success === false) {
        console.log(returnValue.message);
    }
}

$(function () {

    if (typeof location.origin === "undefined") {
        window.location.origin = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host;
    }

    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {

        var childIFrame = $("#editorFrame");
        if (!empowerInstance) {
            empowerInstance = EditorAPI.getInstance(childIFrame[0].contentWindow, window.location.origin);
        }
        empowerInstance.document.hasChanged(hasChangedCallback);// Need to wait for completion 

        var target = $(e.target).attr("data-EditorUrl"); // activated tab
        childIFrame.attr("src", target);

    });
});
```

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: I don't fully understand your code yet, but the answer to your question in general is "use a callback function".

Comment: You can user a callback functions or promises. Promises are not supported by all browsers so you can use webpack or babel to mnahe that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've refactored your code to show how this can be done using promises.

```js
function onClick_btnSendMessage() {
  var childIFrame = window.document.getElementById("editorFrame");
  if (!empowerInstance) {
    empowerInstance = EditorAPI.getInstance(childIFrame.contentWindow, window.location.origin);
  }
  var doc = empowerInstance.document;
  return hasChanged(doc).then(function() { return save(doc) })
}


function hasChanged(doc) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    doc.hasChanged(function(returnValue) {
      if (returnValue.success === true && returnValue.isDirty === true) {
        resolve(returnValue)
      } else {
        reject(returnValue)
      }
    })
  })
}

function save(doc) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    doc.save(function(returnValue) {
      if (returnValue.success === false) {
        console.log(returnValue.message);
        reject(returnValue)
      } else {
        resolve(returnValue)
      }
    })
  })
}

// ------

$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function(e) {

  onClick_btnSendMessage().then(function() {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("data-EditorUrl"); // activated tab
    var childIFrame = $("#editorFrame");
    childIFrame.attr("src", target);

  }).catch(function(error) {
     // handle the error
     console.error('Error!', error)
  })


});
```

Comment: I don't know if the usage of the rejects are correct, the only time I can think of that they would be used is if there was an error being trapped.

Comment: @StephenPatten that depends on your use case. Personally I think that if a save operation fails, the promise representing this operation should be rejected, but you can resolve the promise if you like.

Comment: should have clarified, the reject at the save is correct, but hasChanged is awkward being in the else block, that just means we don't call save. I'm a noob with this stuff so sorry if I'm not understanding usage correctly

Comment: I thought not calling save was the point, no? the condition in the if statement is false, so what should happen now? - I've updated the answer to show how error handling can be added

Comment: You are correct, if it's not dirty don't call save, but that doesn't mean its invalid, just not dirty  so using reject didn't seem right, that all.

Comment: I used resolve in both branches of the if doc.hasChanged callback function

Answer (score 1):

You can use some [higher order functions](http://eloquentjavascript.net/05_higher_order.html) to do what you want. Instead of passing the `hasChangedCallback` and `saveCallback` directly to the `empowerInstance.document` methods, you'll instead invoke a function that returns those callbacks, but also passes along your own callback that you'll call once all the async operations have finally completed. Here's what it'll look like:

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on("shown.bs.tab", function (e) {
    var target = $(e.target).attr("data-EditorUrl"); // activated tab

    onClick_btnSendMessage(function () {
        var childIFrame = $("#editorFrame");
        childIFrame.attr("src", target);
    });
});

function onClick_btnSendMessage(myCallback) {
    var childIFrame = window.document.getElementById("editorFrame");
    if (!empowerInstance) {
        empowerInstance = EditorAPI.getInstance(childIFrame.contentWindow, window.location.origin);
    }
    empowerInstance.document.hasChanged(getHasChangedCallback(myCallback));
}

function getHasChangedCallback(myCallback) {
    return function hasChangedCallback(returnValue,  myCallback) {
        console.log("empowerInstance.document.hasChanged = " + returnValue.isDirty);
        if (returnValue.success === true && returnValue.isDirty === true) {
            empowerInstance.document.save(getSaveCallback(myCallback));
        }
    } 
}

function getSaveCallback(myCallback) {
    return function saveCallback(returnValue) {
        console.log("empowerInstance.document.save = " + returnValue.success);
        if (returnValue.success === false) {
            console.log(returnValue.message);
        }

        myCallback && myCallback(); // make sure myCallback isn't null before invoking
    }
}
```

It's not exactly attractive, but it should get you what you want.

Comment: Very close! It seems as if the target value is always set to the first tab and never changes after that

Comment: Odd. Is the value of `e.target` changing? Maybe the value of the `data-EditorUrl` attribute is changed while the async stuff is happening? Try moving the `target` assignment outside the callback. I'll edit my answer to reflect.

Comment: Yes, e.target is changed on each click of the tab. I've tried it without edits (dirty false) and with edits (dirty true) same behavior.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about the book, I'm going to start reading that someday :)

Comment: The function being passed to onClick_btnSendMessage is never being invoked

Comment: This seems like a very inconvenient and brittle way to do this, needing to pass your callback through like that